# Parallel processing with xargs in bash

Tags: python, bash, openstack, xargs

I had a small script where I would source into each openstack's tenant and fetch some output with the help of python. It took too long for the reports to get generated and I was suggested to use `xargs`. My earlier code was like below.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /scripts/cloud01/floating_list

rm -rf ./reports/openstack_reports/
mkdir -p ./reports/openstack_reports/

source ../creds/base
for tenant in A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T
do
  source ../creds/$tenant
  python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py > ./reports/openstack_reports/$tenant.html

done
lftp -f ./lftp_script
```

Now I have put xargs in the script and the script looks something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /scripts/cloud01/floating_list

rm -rf ./reports/openstack_reports/
mkdir -p ./reports/openstack_reports/

source ../creds/base

# Need xargs idea below
cat tenants_list.txt | xargs -P 8 -I '{}' # something that takes the tenant name and source
TENANT_NAME={}
python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py > ./reports/openstack_reports/$tenant.html
lftp -f ./lftp_script
```

In this script how am I supposed to implement `source ../creds/$tenant`? Because while each tenant is dealt with, it needs to be sourced as well and I am not sure how to include that with xargs for parallel execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` can't easily run a shell function ... but it can run a shell.

```
# If the tenant names are this simple, don't put them in a file
printf '%s\n' {A..T} |
xargs -P 8 -I {} bash -c 'source ../creds/"$0"
      python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py > ./reports/openstack_reports/"$0".html' {}
```

Somewhat obscurely, the argument after `bash -c '...'` gets exposed as `$0` inside the script.

If you want to keep the tenants in a file, `xargs -a filename` is a good way to avoid the [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat), though it's not portable to all `xargs` implementations. (Redirecting with `xargs ... <filename` is obviously completely portable.)

For efficiency, you could refactor the script to loop over as many arguments as possible:

```
printf '%s\n' {A..T} |
xargs -n 3 -P 8 bash -c 'for tenant; do
      source ../creds/"$tenant"
      python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py > ./reports/openstack_reports/"$tenant".html
  done' _
```

This will run a maximum of 8 parallel shell instances with a maximum of 3 tenants assigned to each (so in actual fact only 7 instances), though with this small number of arguments, the difference in performance is probably negligible.

Because we are now actually receiving a list of arguments, we pass `_` as the value to populate `$0` with (just because it needs to be set to something, in order to get the real arguments in place properly).

If the `source` might make modifications which are not always guaranteed to be overwritten by the `source` in the next iteration (say, some tenants have variables which need to be unset for some other tenants?) that complicates matters, but maybe post a separate question if you really actually need help resolving that; or just fall back to the first variant where each tenant is run in a separate shell instance.

Comment: thanks so much. I am getting the result as expected. Accepting your answer. This does land me into some other issues which is from my python file but that is another story now. :)

Comment: adding xargs increased CPU load on the server from which I am requesting the data. I added sleep of 10 seconds to create a small lag. Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Parallel processing by definition increases load. If the remote server is not prepared to handle that sort of load, reduce parallelism, perhaps only by a bit (4 instead of 8 maybe?) but eventually back to serialized if that's more convenient for the system as a whole.

Comment: If your Python script accesses a remote server and the Python API allows you to set a priority or "nice" level, that would allow you to communicate to the server that this is something which is allowed to take a while longer if the load is high; but this is going pretty far into speculative country.

Comment: I do not have that authority to set priority on nice level. And I am also required to generate reports faster but keep load to a minimum. It's like a deadlock. :(

Comment: Without knowing what your Python script does it's hard to suggest improvements. If you can amortize the cost over a longer time the load increase at any given time will be negligible. But if the report needs to show the status of a volatile resource in near real time, of course you can't have a result which might be several minutes old.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /scripts/cloud01/floating_list

rm -rf ./reports/openstack_reports/
mkdir -p ./reports/openstack_reports/

source ../creds/base
doit() {
  source ../creds/"$1"
  python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py > ./reports/openstack_reports/"$1".html
}
env_parallel doit ::: {A..T}
lftp -f ./lftp_script
```

`env_parallel` copies the environment into each command - including functions. It then runs `parallel` which runs one job per core in parallel.

Depending on the task it may be faster or slower to run more or fewer in parallel. Adjust with `-j8` for 8 jobs in parallel or `-j200%` for 2 jobs per core.