# use xargs and keep CPU load of remote server to minimum

Tags: python, multithreading, bash, openstack, xargs

I used xargs for parallel processing. This thread follows what I had. [Parallel processing with xargs in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937446/parallel-processing-with-xargs-in-bash)
But the parallel processing increased CPU load. I was running the script for 57 openstack tenants to fetch results from them. This report is running every 2 hours which is causing CPU spike.

To decrease the load, I thought of adding the random sleep time...something like below but it didn't do much help. I am not sure if I can use `NICE` to set a priority because the results I am fetching are from openstack server. If it's possible, please let me know.

I could remove the parallel processing but this will take 6 hours for me to get all the reports from tenants. So that is not an option.

If there is any other way to optimize this...any ideas or suggestions would be great.

```
source ../creds/base
printf '%s\n' A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P |

xargs -n 3 -P 8 bash -c 'for tenant; do
      source ../creds/"$tenant"
      python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py "$tenant"> ./reports/openstack_reports/"$tenant".html
      sleep $[ ( $RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ]s
done' _
```

Python file

```
with open('../floating_list/testReports/'+tenant_file+'.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    fields = ['Name', 'Volume', 'Flavor', 'Image', 'Floating IP']
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    try:
        for i in servers:
            import io, json
            with open('../floating_list/testReports/'+tenant_file+'.json', 'w') as e:
                e.write(check_output(['openstack', 'server', 'show', i.name, '-f', 'json']))
            with open('../floating_list/testReports/'+tenant_file+'.json', 'r') as a:
                data = json.load(a)
                name.append(i.name)
                volume = data.get('os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached', None) 
                if volume:
                    vol = [d.get('id', {}) for d in volume if volume]
                    vol_name_perm = []
                    for i in vol:
                        try:
                            vol_name1 = (check_output(['openstack', 'volume', 'show', i,  '-c', 'name', '-f', 'value'])).rstrip()
                            vol_name_perm.append(vol_name1)
                        except:
                            vol_name_perm.append('Error')
                    vol_join = ','.join(vol_name_perm)
                    vol_name.append(vol_join)
                else:
                    vol_name.append('None')
                ...

        zipped = [(name), (vol_name),(flavor),(image),(addr)]
        result = zip(*zipped)
        for i in result:
            wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            wr.writerow(i)
    except (CalledProcessError, IndexError) as e:
        print (e)
        print("except", i.name)
```

**WITH GNU PARALLEL**

```
printf '%s\n' A B C D E F | parallel --eta -j 2 --load 40% --noswap 'for tenant; do
      source ../creds/"$tenant"
      python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py "$tenant"> ./reports/openstack_reports/"$tenant".html
done'
```

I get syntax error near unexpected token `A'

**WORKAROUND**

I am able to manage the load with xargs -n 1 -p 3 for now. This gives me reports within 2 hours. I still want to explore my options with GNU Parallel as suggested by Ole Tange

Comment: Like I commented on your other question just now, optimizing the internals of `openstack_resouce_list.py` would seem like the most fruitful option to explore, but we can't help you with that without seeing the code and understanding what it's supposed to do.

Comment: If you can have each tenant report its status, say, every 5 minutes into a central server, generating the report would get you results which are fresh to the latest 5 minutes without any significant load from compiling the report itself.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `-n 3` with `-n 1`?

Comment: **GNU Parallel** would be pretty much a *"drop in replacement"* for `xargs` and it has the new `--load` and `--limit` options which throttle jobs according to CPU load....

Comment: @Cyrus, -n 1 did not work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I definitely will try this one GNU Parallel

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I worked on it, does my edit make sense? I read about GNU and still understanding.

Comment: https://docs.openstack.org/python-novaclient/pike/ would allow you to at least avoid the overhead of running `openstack` commands in a subprocess for each query. If you want to report more or less the full state of each instance, running just two or three queries (servers, volumes, groups?) and parsing the results you get back into your own data structures will likely offer some improvements if the overhead for each call is still significant.

Comment: Forgetting all the parallel stuff for a moment, can you show the first 2 commands that need running just on their own please? I am failing to see the point of your `for` loop...

Comment: I source into each file which has openstack creds, and A B C that you see are the tenants themselves. (57 tenants that I have). so for loop goes over each and every tenant and generate a report.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The linked earlier question from the OP probably provides the background you are looking for.

Comment: but I doubt if we cannot control the load of CPU and memory of a remote server from GNU Parallel.

Comment: @tripleee, I must use openstack-clients now, that was one resort I had hoped could help me.

Comment: Can you change the question so it is much more explicit that the server which becomes loaded is a _remote_ server and _not_ the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use GNU Parallel with `niceload` (part of GNU Parallel):

```
niceload parallel --nice 11 --bar "'source ../creds/{};
  python ../tools/openstack_resource_list.py {} > ./reports/openstack_reports/{}.html'" ::: {A..F}
```

Comment: but this is a remote server which I query. Will GNU Parallel control the load of other server?

Comment: If the overloading happens on the remote machine, then you need to write some code to give that to GNU Parallel. Eg. by using `--limit myscript`.

Comment: I have to try this.